# Covariant derivative of functions between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold, $E$ some vector bundle on that manifold and $\nabla$ a covariant derivative on $M \rightarrow E$. Let $N$ be another manifolds and $f \in C^{\infty}(M,N)$.

How can we define $\nabla f$ then?

I know that for some $g \in C^{\infty}(M)$, $\nabla_X g=X(g)$ be what if the function is not $\mathbb{R}$ valued?

I am asking to understand the definition of a wave equation on manifolds as defined here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: $u^*$? in $u^*TM$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment

Comment: WHAT IS THE $u^*$?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection is a Riemannian object: there seems to be missing some metric in your question?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection is, by definition, on the tangent bundle, not on an arbitrary (even Riemannian) vector bundle.

Comment: It's better to give more context. Your $\nabla$ is likely not the Levi-Civite connection, and $\nabla f$ is more commonly denoted $df$.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question and give more details!

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: I have edited again and generalized my question

Comment: I really cant see where that $E$ is coming from. Can you include the original reference? I will take a look.

Comment: You say $\nabla$ is a connection but you don’t say of what. Tangent vector fields on $M$? Sections of $E$? Sections of $f*T_*N$? The map $f: M \rightarrow N$ has nothing to do with $E$, so what’s the relevance of $E$ here? In fact, the definition of the differential of $f$ does not require a connection at all. It’s commonly known as the Jacobian of $f$.

Comment: I have added the source, it's Global Wave Maps on Robertson–Walker Spacetimes by YVONNE CHOQUET-BRUHAT